# Windows 8 Store App and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, windows-8, store

The snippet below is from a Windows 8 store app in c# and xaml.
I have put this code together from variou samples on the web so this may not be the neatest way of doing this. Most of it is from the Grid template supplied in VS2012 and I have hooked up my web api as the source of the data

Please explain the following

When i call the Get method all works fine and i get data back into the xaml view
When i uncomment the Take(10) in the same method i get no data back.

It seems any attempt to put an extension method of a LINQ variety just stops the data being returned and also gives no indication why, it complies fine!

Any help appreciated

Thanks 
Mark

```
public class TeamDataSource
{
    private static TeamDataSource _sampleDataSource = new TeamDataSource();

    private ObservableCollection<TeamDataItem> _items = new ObservableCollection<TeamDataItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<TeamDataItem> Items
    {
        get { return this._items; }
    }

    public TeamDataSource()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TeamDataItem> Get()
    {
        var thisdata = _sampleDataSource.Items;
        return thisdata;//.Take(10);
    }

    private async void Initialize()
    {
        using (var client = new DataServiceClient())
        {
            List<TeamDataItem> list = await client.Download<List<TeamDataItem>>("/teams");

            foreach (var i in list.OrderByDescending(t => t.Points).ThenByDescending(t => t.GoalDiff))
            {
                TeamDataItem team = i;
                _items.Add(team);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does .Take(10).ToList<TeamDataItem>() work?

Comment: No it didn't i am afraid

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Take` doesn't immediately enumerate the items.  It defers enumeration until either `foreach` is called on it or `GetEnumerator` is called on it.  In this case the collection it is enumerating is disposed (as soon as the `Get` content ends) and so when it finally enumerates the items, there are no items anymore.  Try adding `thisdata.GetEnumerator();` as a line before your return statement.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.

Comment: That has made no difference. I wonder whether it has something to do with the async/await. I know when this normally happens doing a ToList() gives you something to iterate over when the query is still in that deferred state.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was quite obvious in the end. As I was using aync and await, the call was immediately returning before the data had arrived. Therefore nothing for the Take(4) to work on.

Only problem now is when can i tell the task has completed?